# Need regular expression to replace before and after while keeping the numbers in the middle

Tags: regex, backreference, ultraedit

I have the following:

```
itemid=44'>Red Flower</a>
```

I need it to be this:

```
_ITEMID_START_44_ITEMID_END_
```

Can this be done with regular expressions? I need to keep the id (44 in the example), and replace everything on the left with _ITEMID_START_and everything on the right with _ITEMID_END_.

Note: The itemid is one digit or two but never no more than two.

I found something about tagged regular expressions and backreferences which seems like it would work but the syntax is killing me.

I tried this (and other attempts):

```
Find What: ^(\bitemid=\b)^([0-9][0-9]^)\b'>\b[a-z]+\b</a>\b)
Replace With: ^(\b_ITEMID_START_\b^2^(\b_ITEMID_END_\b
```

I am using UltraEdit to do the find and replace in over 20,000 *.html files. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) and also first solution of [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) work both in UltraEdit with selecting **Perl** as regular expression engine. The second search string of [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj) requires removing backslash left of character `'` in search string to work in UltraEdit.

UltraEdit has 3 regular expression engines: **UltraEdit**, **Unix** and **Perl**.

The search string in the question is a mixture of UltraEdit and Perl regular expression syntax and therefore does not work.

With **UltraEdit** reguar expression engine:

```
Find what: itemid=^([0-9]+^)*</a>
Replace with: _ITEMID_START_^1_ITEMID_END_
```

With **Unix** or **Perl** regular expression engine:

```
Find what: itemid=([0-9]+).*</a>
Replace with: _ITEMID_START_\1_ITEMID_END_
```

More secure because non greedy, but only with **Perl** regex engine:

```
Find what: itemid=(\d+).*?</a>
Replace with: _ITEMID_START_\1_ITEMID_END_
```

IDM published the power tips [tagged expressions](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/tagged_expressions.html) for **UltraEdit** regex engine and [Perl regular expressions: Backreferences](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/perl-regular-expressions-backreferences.html) for **Perl** regex engine.

Comment: Thank you so much. The three choices in UE confused me as I don't thoroughly understand basic regular expressions, more less having a choice of three :) Your example using UE's regular expression worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match everything and capture only the digits which was just after to the `itemid=`. And in the replacement part, the whole line is replaced with `_ITEMID_START_\1_ITEMID_END_` (`\1` represents the first captured group. It may vary for different languages)

```
.*(?<=\bitemid=)([0-9]{1,2}).*
```

And the substitution would be,

```
_ITEMID_START_\1_ITEMID_END_
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aW0sT4/8)

---

If you just want to replace only,

```
itemid=44'>Red Flower</a>
```

with

```
_ITEMID_START_44_ITEMID_END_
```

Then your regex would be,

```
\bitemid=([0-9]{1,2})\'>[^<]*<\/a>
```

And the substitution would be,

```
_ITEMID_START_\1_ITEMID_END_
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Find What:    \bitemid=([0-9][0-9]?)'>[^<]*</a>
Replace With: _ITEMID_START_\1_ITEMID_END_
```

A replacement string is a normal string, and all the regex special characters (except for the backreference) loose their special meaning.

`\b` the word boundary is the limit between a character that come from the `\w` character class *(a shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`)* and an other character.

Note: I can't try it with ultraedit, if you obtain a literal `\1`, replace it with `$1`